# of which confusion

Tags: meaning, sentence, relative-clauses, possessive-of-which

I have serious problem with understanding stucture of the following "of which" sentences, especially the "of which's". Could anyone help me by rephrasing them in an explanatory way?

> "But the press cannot expose that of which it is denied knowledge."

> "The cause and that of which it is the cause go together."

Comment: Simply replace "that" with "the thing".

Answer (score 2):

The following rephrased sentences remove the *of which* phrasing but keep the essential meaning. I have tried to also keep a consistent pattern of rephrasing, and I've emphasized the changed words.

1. But the press cannot expose that of which it is denied knowledge.
   → But the press cannot expose **what** it is denied knowledge **of**.
2. The cause and that of which it is the cause go together.
   → The cause and **what** it is the cause **of** go together.

Answer (score 2):

"But the press cannot expose that of which it is denied knowledge."

> That of which it is denied knowledge --> *what it does not (or cannot) know*.

> But the press cannot expose *what it does not (or cannot) know*.

"The cause and that of which it is the cause go together."

> That of which it is the cause --> *its effects*

> "The cause and *its effects* go together."